# Access Linux ethercat CoE interface as a normal (not sudo) user

Tags: interface, sudo, ethercat

I need to read/write the ethercat CoE interface as a normal (not sudo) user.
Is there a command to do this at Linux?
Or perhaps a systemd configuration that would work just like how udev rules work for making USB devices accessible for read/write without sudo access?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the capability of the executable that accesses Ethercat port with setcap command.

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /path/to/executable
```

Then, you can run the executable as a normal user.

To register this command for a startup script, such as in Ubuntu, create the following systemd service file.
$ sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/setcatp.service

File content should be like as below

```
[Unit]
Description=Set capabilities on executable that accesses Ethercat port
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/setcap cap_net_raw+ep /home/ubuntu/agv_ws/build/servo_controller/servo_controller/servo_controller
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next, set up the systemd

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable setcap.service
$ sudo systemctl start setcap.service
$ sudo systemctl status setcap.service
```